# php date range selecting data for a year only

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a php code which is selecting item from database from startdate to enddate. However, if i select between a date in 2017 and another date in 2017, it works fine, if i select between a date in 2018 and another date in 2018, it works fine, but if i select between 2017 to 2018, its not working

Below is my code

```
/// this is the php selecting
if (array_key_exists('generate', $_POST)){
 $startdate = ($_POST['startdate']);
 $enddate = ($_POST['enddate']);
 $getoutletid = ($_POST['outletid']);
    }

//then this is the query
$q = "
SELECT * 
  FROM ".TBL_SALES_LOGS." 
 WHERE dateofsales BETWEEN '$startdate' and '$enddate' 
 ORDER 
    BY timestamp
    "
```

This is the return date format of my code when i echo on same page
from 11/06/2017 to 01/09/2018

Comment: Please give several examples of 'startdate' / 'enddate' - values.

Comment: could you post table structure ?? and exact example (start and end date), which is not working

Comment: what date format are you passing into the SQL query?

Comment: without having enough data it is unclear, what is his/her actual question

Comment: Forget about the PHP. Instead, see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: this is what my date return if i echo on the page.    11/06/2017 to 01/09/2018

Comment: Thanks all i have updated my question

Comment: @Ademaintain Pls update your post with your table structure detail. Also, update start and end date for which you get correct output

Answer (score 1):

```html
<?php

echo('this will work only you stored in tables unix time as time() provide :'.time().'<hr>');
$july=mktime(0, 0, 0, 7, 1, 2017);

$startdate=mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2017);//from first jannuary 2017 =you should use the date from were you define the time interval

$enddate=mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2018);// first jannuary 2018 =you should use the date until you define the time interval

if(($july>=$startdate)and($july<=$enddate)) print('Success ,the date='.date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A',$july).' provided as time() does =Unix timestamp IS IN CHOOSED INTERVAL<BR>');else print('the date ='.date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A',$july).' provided doesn`t below to interval');
echo('<hr>');
$q = '
SELECT * 
  FROM ".TBL_SALES_LOGS." 
 WHERE dateofsales BETWEEN '.$startdate.' and '.$enddate.' 
 ORDER 
BY timestamp
';

echo($q.'<hr>');

$q = '
SELECT * 
  FROM ".TBL_SALES_LOGS." 
 WHERE dateofsales <= '.$startdate.' and dateofsales >='.$enddate.' 
 ORDER 
BY timestamp
';

echo($q.'<hr>');



?>
```

OUTPUT:

```html
this will work only you stored in tables unix time as time() provide :1515415011<hr>Success ,the date=Saturday 1st of July 2017 12:00:00 AM provided as time() does =Unix timestamp IS IN CHOOSED INTERVAL<BR><hr>
SELECT * 
  FROM ".TBL_SALES_LOGS." 
 WHERE dateofsales BETWEEN 1483225200 and 1514761200 
 ORDER 
    BY timestamp
    <hr>
SELECT * 
  FROM ".TBL_SALES_LOGS." 
 WHERE dateofsales <= 1483225200 and dateofsales >=1514761200 
 ORDER 
    BY timestamp
    <hr>
```